# Splitting a string and storing it in a member HashMap requires that the string is borrowed for `'a`

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker, borrowing

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

pub struct MyMap<'a> {
    data: HashMap<&'a str, usize>,
    analyzer: Analyzer<'a>,
}

pub struct Analyzer<'b> {
    _marker: &'b PhantomData<()>,
}

impl<'b> Analyzer<'b> {
    pub fn check(&self, data: &'b str) -> bool {
        data.len() > 10
    }
}

impl<'a> MyMap<'a> {
    pub fn get_data(&mut self, expr: &str) -> Vec<usize> {
        let tokens = expr
            .split_whitespace()
            .map(|s| s.to_string())
            .collect::<Vec<String>>();

        let mut ret = Vec::new();

        for s in &tokens {
            if self.analyzer.check(s) {
                self.data.insert(s, s.len()); // <- Removing this line solve the problem, why?
                ret.push(s.len());
            }
        }

        ret
    }
}
```

I'm getting the compiler error:

```
error[E0597]: `tokens` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:28:18
   |
19 | impl<'a> MyMap<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
28 |         for s in &tokens {
   |                  ^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
29 |             if self.analyzer.check(s) {
30 |                 self.data.insert(s, s.len()); // <- Removing this line solve the problem, why?
   |                 ---------------------------- argument requires that `tokens` is borrowed for `'a`
...
36 |     }
   |     - `tokens` dropped here while still borrowed
```

From what I understand, the lifetime of `tokens` is tied to the method `get_data` which is lower than the lifetime `'a`.

Is there a way to borrow `tokens` for `'a`, or how can I solve this error?

Comment: `str` is a part of a `String`. A part. It doesn't own the `String`, but depends on it. So who should own the `String` that `str` inside your `HashMap` depend on? Because `tokens`, which is a vector of `String`s, will be destroyed on the end of your function. So what should own these `tokens`? Maybe instead of storing parts of others `String`s in your hashmap, just store a new string object? That way your hashmap will not depend on `String`s of others.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b1d11eb297bdcbdece5e641fe2b429c)